# Can we have the "50 more" link return items of the same type, please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools

When working my may through items in [/tools/flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged), I find it more efficient to handle one flag type at a time.

If there are many items for a flag type, only 50 random posts are shown at a time which is great. However, when I reach the bottom of the list and click "50 more", the selected flag type is forgotten and I end up with 50 random questions of all types.

**Feature Request**: Can the "50 more" link take into account the selected flag type?

[image: Sir, can I have some more?]

Sure, I can achieve that quickly using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), or create a userscript to apply the current querystring to the "50 more" link. However, an official solution would be nice.

Comment: I agree that this should be fixed.  In the mean time, I've included a userscript fix for this in a collection of small fixes like this that I'm calling the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen [[meta-tag:status-completed]]; SOUP sheds another fix.

Comment: @michaelb958: Cool! I'll release 1.8.2 once this goes live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of flags shown on that page is no longer random, so I replaced that whole line with a pager that preserves filtering by flag type.

Should be live on MSO in `rev. 2014.2.27.2000` and elsewhere in `rev. 2014.2.27.1409`.

Comment: [There seems to be a slight problem with the pager.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224664/10k-flag-review-pager-always-shows-page-1-as-current)

Comment: @Ilmari Noted; will fix. Thanks!