# Don't repeat (or let us skip) posts when requesting next page on 10k tools' Flagged Posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, 10k-tools

I usually review the [Not an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answernotananswer) flagged posts list, which is the one with the most pending flags by the way (most of the time around 100 flags?). It is a great way to comfortably handle those posts and contribute to the site, but it has a couple of issues that keep me from using them as much as I'd like to:

I usually flag clearly-not-an-answer posts, and just skip the ones in tags I don't have enough knowledge about, or the ones I'm not sure about how to proceed with (I'm not certain enough to flag as invalid most of the flags). This means that when I request the next page of 50 flagged posts, I see many of the posts I just skipped.

The page shows 50 posts in random order. I understand this is intentional and aimed to avoid focusing handling of the flags on specific posts based on some ordering criteria. But when we're done scrolling through the 50 posts on the list, we can only get 50 more flagged posts ([losing the chosen flag type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150069/169503)), and what is worse, having repeated posts all over.

This is disencouraging me from keeping reviewing flags once I've gone through the first page of the list.

Could the *Showing 50 random posts; [get 50 more](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged)* link avoid showing posts already shown on the current post list?

Or could we have a "Skip" option (similar to the ones on the review queues) on the flagged posts in the list, just to indicate we're not sure about them and don't want them to appear again?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think just automatically skipping any previously shown posts is a good idea (what if you get interrupted while reviewing?), but **I'd very much like an explicit "skip" button.**

- Sometimes, I just can't tell if the flags are valid or not.  Maybe the topic of the post is so far outside my knowledge that I can't even tell if it's a good post or not, or maybe the post is just so borderline that I don't feel comfortable either disputing the existing flags or piling my own on top of them.
- Sometimes, I just feel that the best thing to do with a post is nothing at all.  Maybe it's a poor but not-quite-NAA answer that just deserves a downvote, or maybe it's going to be auto-deleted by Community ♦ soon anyway.

I don't really want to flag such posts, since I wouldn't flag them if I came across them outside review, but I also don't want to dispute the existing flags in case a mod does find them helpful (since, AIUI, mods can't actually override the "disputed" status on flags).  But the only third option currently is to leave such posts alone until a mod gets around to handling them, which means they keep cluttering up the review page.

Some way to say *"I don't know if those flags are good, stop asking me already!"* would be nice.