# Why aren't the flagged posts random?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools

Everytime I refresh the [NAA flagged posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answernotananswer), I get the same 50 each time.

I'm asking why aren't they random because at the bottom of the page:

> Showing 50 random posts; get 50 more

If it's refreshed after some time period, can I [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) that it be generated at page refresh?

Additionally, the link to `get 50 more` just goes back to `https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged`

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/ <- Obligatory.

Comment: You know, I think something's broken.  get 50 more isn't working right now.

Comment: To the last part: [Can we have the "50 more" link return items of the same type, please?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150069) (which also implies the list should already be random, but that doesn't seem to be the case)

Comment: The lack of randomness was [implemented by Jarrod in December 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212286/163863). Admittedly I preferred the random ordering, as it just seems a "pile-on" fest, currently.

Comment: @Matt I like feasts. I don't like fests.

Comment: @FreshPrince: as do I, shame I actually meant fest :P

Answer (score 2):

As Matt noted in the comments, the flags are no longer random due to [another bug fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212285/flagged-question-count-is-wrong/212286#212286).

That fix is here to stay, so since the list is no longer random, I've replaced that line with a pager that will allow you to navigate back and forth through the list. Should be live on MSO in `rev. 2014.2.27.2000` and elsewhere in `rev. 2014.2.27.1409`.

Comment: Can the `get 50 more` link do something useful?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No. ;)

Comment: Can I have a unicorn?

Comment: Hmmmmmm. Maybe.

Comment: With this new de-randomized flags page, I'm *really* missing [some kind of a "skip" / "ignore" / "no action needed" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223216/why-arent-the-flagged-posts-random). I don't want to have to keep casting dozens of meaningless pile-on flags just to get to the part of the list where one can actually contribute something useful.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Hrm. If a post needs flagging, then I'd say you should flag it. If it doesn't, you can dispute the flags that are there. I don't think it's worth bolting on a skip onto this right now - I'm still holding out hope for a more review-like interface for flag queues.

Comment: @AnnaLear Like the suggested edits?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Yeah, something along those lines. As far as I know there are no concrete plans in place, but I'm an optimist.

Comment: @AnnaLear I'll upvote that.